# Unable to use uniq -c to print counts for all lines

Tags: awk, uniq

I would like to use uniq to count the number of occurrences of each line, excluding the numerical value at the beginning of the line (example: 0000:01:00.0)

Each occurrence occurs more than once. There may be situations where each occurrence only occurs once.

**Sample Input**

```
[root@cpod-compute-1 ~]# for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do lspci -Dm | grep $i; done
0000:01:00.0 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"
0000:01:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"
0000:0a:00.1 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
0000:0a:00.2 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
0000:0a:00.3 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
```

**Expected output**

```
2  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"
3  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
```

**Example of non-working case**

```
[root@cpod-compute-1 ~]#  for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}' | sort | uniq -c; done
      1  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"
      1  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Connection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5" 
      1  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
      1  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
      1  "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "Ethernet Controller X710 for 10GbE SFP+" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Ethernet Converged NIC X710-DA"
```

**Outputs collected**
- I do not see any unexpected characters in the outputs collected.

```
[root@cpod-compute-1 ~]#  for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}' | od -c; done
0000000       "   E   t   h   e   r   n   e   t       c   o   n   t   r
0000020   o   l   l   e   r   "       "   I   n   t   e   l       C   o
0000040   r   p   o   r   a   t   i   o   n   "       "   I   3   5   0
0000060       G   i   g   a   b   i   t       N   e   t   w   o   r   k
0000100       C   o   n   n   e   c   t   i   o   n   "       -   r   0
0000120   1       "   C   i   s   c   o       S   y   s   t   e   m   s
0000140       I   n   c   "       "   D   e   v   i   c   e       0   0
0000160   d   5   "  \n
0000164
0000000       "   E   t   h   e   r   n   e   t       c   o   n   t   r
0000020   o   l   l   e   r   "       "   I   n   t   e   l       C   o
0000040   r   p   o   r   a   t   i   o   n   "       "   I   3   5   0
0000060       G   i   g   a   b   i   t       N   e   t   w   o   r   k
0000100       C   o   n   n   e   c   t   i   o   n   "       -   r   0
0000120   1       "   C   i   s   c   o       S   y   s   t   e   m   s
0000140       I   n   c   "       "   D   e   v   i   c   e       0   0
0000160   d   5   "  \n
0000164

[root@cpod-compute-1 ~]# for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}' | sed -n l; done
 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Conn\
ection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"$
 "Ethernet controller" "Intel Corporation" "I350 Gigabit Network Conn\
ection" -r01 "Cisco Systems Inc" "Device 00d5"$
```

I'm unable to understand what is the difference in the adjacent lines which appear to be duplicate.

Please let me know if any further outputs are required.

Thanks.

Comment: Could you please do mention sample of input and expected output more clearly in your Question(may be as a separate section in your question).

Comment: You provided lots of different outputs but not one sample of the input. Please [edit] your question to show a few lines of concise, testable sample input and the expected output given that input.

Comment: Apologies Ed Morton, the first section is actually Input. I have renamed the heading.

Comment: I will make the input more verbose.

Comment: Your `| sort | uniq -c` should appear after the `done` of the for-loop. Currently, you only do `sort` and `uniq` on a single line. But you want to do it on all the lines. Hence you have to put it after the `for`-loop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code the OP used was:

```
for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do 
   lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}' | sort | uniq -c;
done
```

While it should have read:

```
for i in $(awk -F= '/PCI_SLOT_NAME/{print $2}' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent); do 
   lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
done | sort | uniq -c;
```

The difference between the two cases is that the in the first case you sort the output of **a single** command:

```
lspci -Dm | grep $i | awk '{$1="";print $0}'
```

In the second case, you sort the output of the full for-loop.

An updated version would be the following:

```
awk -F= '(FNR==1){ OFS=FS=(f==0 ? "=" : " "); $0=$0 }
         (f==0) && /PCI_SLOT_NAME/{a[$2];next}
         ($1 in a) {$1=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; print}
        ' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent f=1 <(lspci -Dm) | sort | uniq -c
```

We can now still merge the counting in awk:

```
awk -F= '(FNR==1){ OFS=FS=(f==0 ? "=" : " "); $0=$0 }
         (f==0) && /PCI_SLOT_NAME/{a[$2];next}
         ($1 in a) {$1=""; $0=$0; $1=$1; b[$0]++}
         END{for (i in b) print b[i],i}
        ' /sys/class/net/*/device/uevent f=1 <(lspci -Dm)
```